# Android studio full screen background

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to put a background in my android studio app but it doesn't show the image in full screen . Can someone help ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/start">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: full screen depends on the theme.

Comment: @RiyazAhamed So I can't make it full screen ?

Comment: add this to your theme <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

Comment: Go to styles.xml in values folder and give like <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"/>

Comment: It's still not showing . There is a big white space on the bottom of the screen .